# Horizontal scroll appears on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't understand why do I get the horizontal scroll in this bootstrap website can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong I can't quite understand.

jsfiddle.net/8aAUP/

Comment: Why is vertical scroll a bad thing?

Comment: Are you actually referring to the horizontal scroll bar? The vertical one is there because the amount of content is taller than the screen height. Unless you explicitly hide it, it's going to be there.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was talking about the horizontal bar.

Comment: @Elezar yes, sorry I'm a little tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are using this DOM:

```
.row
  .container
    .row
```

Row is a class which is situated for placing into `.conatiner`, so if you remove the outer `.row`, it will work as you want.

Comment: I understand now and It's working. What is weird is that the same problem didn't appeared on other sites where I used the same technique.

Comment: @Netra maybe different version of TWBS?